# How to retrieve Tables with their sub-tables as json in rails?

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails, ruby

For exemple I have several models like: Name, Location, Login,...and I want to get all tables with their sub-tables combined as a json after querying in rails, like this:

```json
{
      "name": {
        "title": "mr",
        "first": "brad",
        "last": "gibson"
      },
      "location": {
        "street": "9278 new road",
        "city": "kilcoole",
        "state": "waterford",
        "postcode": "93027",
        "coordinates": {
          "latitude": "20.9267",
          "longitude": "-7.9310"
        },
        "timezone": {
          "offset": "-3:30",
          "description": "Newfoundland"
        }
      },
      "login": {
        "uuid": "155e77ee-ba6d-486f-95ce-0e0c0fb4b919",
        "username": "silverswan131",
        "password": "firewall",
        "salt": "TQA1Gz7x",
        "md5": "dc523cb313b63dfe5be2140b0c05b3bc",
        "sha1": "7a4aa07d1bedcc6bcf4b7f8856643492c191540d",
        "sha256": "74364e96174afa7d17ee52dd2c9c7a4651fe1254f471a78bda0190135dcd3480"
      }
}
```

Comment: You should have associations between your models (has_one, belongs_to) and then serialize the response. Many ways to build the JSON (serialize), either by hand or use a serializing class https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/tree/0-10-stable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're only using Rails, then you can get most of this functionality with the `.as_json` method provided by [ActiveModel::Serializers::JSON](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html)

You can produce JSON similar to your example like so:

```rb
name = Name.first
location = Location.first
login = Login.first

ActiveRecord::Base.include_root_in_json = true

{
  **name.as_json(except: :id),
  **location.as_json(include: {
    coordinates: { only: [:latitude, :longitude] },
    timezone: { only: [:offset, :description] },
  }),
  **login.as_json(except: :id)
}
```